# Disable double sided normals

Tags: 3d-view, normals

I'm currently using the latest version of Blender and I've noticed something different. Models seem to render both sides of a model when in texture mode - I recall in previous versions that only 1 side would show while the other would be invisible (which is what I want). I'm exporting my models to a game engine and it shows only shows the surface normals on 1 side. Does anyone know how to have Blender only show 1 side of a face?

Here's an image:[image]

The left window is what I expect, but the faces on the right window I expect to be invisible.

Answer (score 5):

Literally just figured this out about 10 seconds after posting this. Here's the solution for anyone with the same problem:

Find the Shading section press <kbd>N</kbd> to open the Properties panel - should appear on the right side of your window. Find the Shading section in that panel and make sure 'Backface Culling' is checked. Voila.

Comment: This helped me with a possibly unrelated normals issue, where the polygons seemed to overlap with themselves (still not sure how this happened in first place)